# Multiple SQL joins

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I need to execute a query To retrieve data from multiple tables but I'm rather confused on how to do it all at once.

```
Books: _ISBN , BookTitle, Edition, Year, PublisherID, Pages, Rating
Categories: _CategoryID, Category
Categories_Books: _Categories_Category_ID, _Books_ISBN
Publishers: _Publisherid, Publisher
Writers: _WriterID, LastName
Writers_Books: _Writers_WriterID, _Books_ISBN
```

`Categories_Books` and `Writers_Books` are the intermediate tables to help me implement many to many relationships between the tables.

I need a single query with multiple joins to select:

- Title, Edition, Year, Pages, Rating from Books
- Category from Categories
- Publisher from Publishers
- LastName from Writers

Answer (score 113, accepted):

It will be something like this:

```
SELECT b.Title, b.Edition, b.Year, b.Pages, b.Rating, c.Category, p.Publisher, w.LastName
FROM
    Books b
    JOIN Categories_Book cb ON cb._ISBN = b._Books_ISBN
    JOIN Category c ON c._CategoryID = cb._Categories_Category_ID
    JOIN Publishers p ON p._PublisherID = b.PublisherID
    JOIN Writers_Books wb ON wb._Books_ISBN = b._ISBN
    JOIN Writer w ON w._WritersID = wb._Writers_WriterID
```

You use the `join` statement to indicate which fields from table A map to table B. I'm using aliases here thats why you see `Books b` the `Books` table will be referred to as `b` in the rest of the query. This makes for less typing.

FYI your naming convention is very strange, I would expect it to be more like this:

```
Book: ID, ISBN , BookTitle, Edition, Year, PublisherID, Pages, Rating
Category: ID, [Name]
BookCategory: ID, CategoryID, BookID
Publisher: ID, [Name]
Writer: ID, LastName
BookWriter: ID, WriterID, BookID
```

Comment: Yes my naming conventions are really really weird on this i know. Looking back at the joins i was executing it was what was confusing me in the first place. Thanks for the help whatsoever.

Answer (score 24):

You can use something like this :

```
SELECT
    Books.BookTitle,
    Books.Edition,
    Books.Year,
    Books.Pages,
    Books.Rating,
    Categories.Category,
    Publishers.Publisher,
    Writers.LastName
FROM Books
INNER JOIN Categories_Books ON Categories_Books._Books_ISBN = Books._ISBN
INNER JOIN Categories ON Categories._CategoryID = Categories_Books._Categories_Category_ID
INNER JOIN Publishers ON Publishers._Publisherid = Books.PublisherID
INNER JOIN Writers_Books ON Writers_Books._Books_ISBN = Books._ISBN
INNER JOIN Writers ON Writers.Writers_Books = _Writers_WriterID.
```

Comment: Sounds good, let's get rid of one of the main differentiators of the site. Go and post it on meta.stackoverflow.com, see what they say. I'm sure everyone will agree with you.

Comment: @Kris this may be homework, but the sql query really simple, so the best way to learn is, in my opinion, to read the query, everything is straight forward and this way he'll learn the correct syntax.

Comment: I for one am glad of answers like this krtek, they show up in Google, when I search for "sql multiple join" and act as a reference for all future users who do the same.

Comment: `INNER` is optional. `JOIN` only will give the same result.

Answer (score 4):

```
 SELECT
 B.Title, B.Edition, B.Year, B.Pages, B.Rating     --from Books
, C.Category                                        --from Categories
, P.Publisher                                       --from Publishers
, W.LastName                                        --from Writers

FROM Books B

JOIN Categories_Books CB ON B._ISBN = CB._Books_ISBN
JOIN Categories_Books CB ON CB.__Categories_Category_ID = C._CategoryID
JOIN Publishers P ON B.PublisherID = P._Publisherid
JOIN Writers_Books WB ON B._ISBN = WB._Books_ISBN
JOIN Writers W ON WB._Writers_WriterID = W._WriterID
```